# Receiving a 415 error when ingesting a document into Watson Discovery service

Tags: watson-discovery

I am trying to **POST** documents to Watson's Discovery service via Postman. It gives me the following not-so-helpful error message no matter what kind document I try:

```
{
"code": 415,
"error": "The request failed. Please try again."}
```

The request looks like:

```
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/7c83f310-0f3a-4ad0-bb71-5f260672cbca/collections/c0080236-aac1-405c-8111-322caa6b0b65/documents?version=2016-12-01
```

with the body containing the file in binary and the credentials in the header.

I can upload these documents fine via the collection dashboard, so I must be doing something wrong. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP status code `415` is titled *Unsupported Media Type*.

There are two levels which can trigger a `415` from Discovery.

1. Discovery demands that the overall HTTP POST request be a multipart form, when adding (or updating) a document (to be precise: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=`…) The file needs to be sent within that multipart form request as a part named `file`.
2. When sending the multipart form, the file you are sending, or possibly just the `Content-Type` header that you are sending for the `file` part, can be rejected. Watson Discovery supports HTML, JSON, PDF and Microsoft Word documents. Anything else will get the `415` response, including if Discovery does not correctly guess the content type. Discovery uses the filename as an aid to guessing what the content type is.

Relevant questions:

- Are you bundling your request up in `multipart/form-data`?
- What kind of file are you sending?
- What is the *name* of the file that you are sending?

Comment: I tried both PDF and Word files. The files I was trying to upload were named ZSQ03011USEN.pdf and XBQ12358USEN.docx. Like I said, they both ingested fine when using the dashboard.  I will try manually specifying the mime/type in the headers.

Comment: Ah! OK. _Another_ thing Discovery demands for adding (or updating) a document is that the _overall_ HTTP POST request be a multipart form (to be precise: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=`…) The file needs to be sent _within_ that multipart form request as a part named `file`. (I guess I should update my answer to say something like this.)